# Compilation Error on PromiseKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to run my project both with Xcode and also using `xcodebuild` from the command line and keep getting `CompileC` errors and other stuff.

You can see in the screenshot what it is complaining about.
[image]

```
The following build commands failed:
[00:19:43][Step 6/11]     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng -compress /Users/qahudl/buildAgent/work/6509768bae61d462/Pods/uservoice-iphone-sdk/Resources/uv_article@2x.png /Users/qahudl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hudl-envetnnuigbnupaygdxbwnwaqtss/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Hudl/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/UserVoice.bundle/uv_article@2x.png
[00:19:43][Step 6/11]   CompileC /Users/qahudl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hudl-envetnnuigbnupaygdxbwnwaqtss/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Hudl/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Pods-PromiseKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CALayer+PromiseKit.o PromiseKit/objc/CALayer+PromiseKit.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[00:19:43][Step 6/11] 
[00:19:43][Step 6/11]   CompileC /Users/qahudl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hudl-envetnnuigbnupaygdxbwnwaqtss/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Hudl/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Pods-PromiseKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/NSURLConnection+PromiseKit.o PromiseKit/objc/NSURLConnection+PromiseKit.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[00:19:43][Step 6/11] CopyPNGFile /Users/qahudl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hudl-envetnnuigbnupaygdxbwnwaqtss/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Hudl/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/UserVoice.bundle/uv_article.png uservoice-iphone-sdk/Resources/uv_article.png
[00:19:43][Step 6/11]   CompileC /Users/qahudl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hudl-envetnnuigbnupaygdxbwnwaqtss/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Hudl/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Pods-PromiseKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/NSNotificationCenter+PromiseKit.o PromiseKit/objc/NSNotificationCenter+PromiseKit.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[00:19:43][Step 6/11]     cd /Users/qahudl/buildAgent/work/6509768bae61d462/Pods
[00:19:43][Step 6/11]   CompileC /Users/qahudl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hudl-envetnnuigbnupaygdxbwnwaqtss/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Hudl/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Pods-PromiseKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/PMKPromise+Pause.o PromiseKit/objc/PMKPromise+Pause.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[00:19:43][Step 6/11]     export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/qahudl/.rbenv/shims:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
[00:19:43][Step 6/11]   CompileC /Users/qahudl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hudl-envetnnuigbnupaygdxbwnwaqtss/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Hudl/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Pods-PromiseKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/PMKPromise+Until.o PromiseKit/objc/PMKPromise+Until.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[00:19:43][Step 6/11]   CompileC /Users/qahudl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hudl-envetnnuigbnupaygdxbwnwaqtss/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Hudl/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Pods-PromiseKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/PMKPromise+When.o PromiseKit/objc/PMKPromise+When.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[00:19:43][Step 6/11]     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng -compress /Users/qahudl/buildAgent/work/6509768bae61d462/Pods/uservoice-iphone-sdk/Resources/uv_article.png /Users/qahudl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hudl-envetnnuigbnupaygdxbwnwaqtss/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Hudl/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/UserVoice.bundle/uv_article.png
[00:19:43][Step 6/11] (6 failures)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that all of the symlinks were dropped somehow, but using [this script](https://gist.github.com/dsibiski/c7758c944697edd2065d) I was able to get it working again. I also had to do something similar for the frameworks included in the project not in CocoaPods.